# Source for washing by your bed

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, sources-mekorot

What is the source in the Halachic literature outside of the [Mishnah Berurah](http://www.mishnaberura.com/Print.asp?NoPrint=True&SeifID=24) who says it is a requirement to place a washing cup by your bed instead of going to the sink to wash your hands upon awakening in the morning?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's from the Zohar.

Comment: anything in the Halachic literature?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11896/what-is-a-source-that-allows-one-to-treat-ones-house-as-all-within-four-amos

Comment: See my answer there.

Comment: See also here for a big discussion with many sources: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37782&st=&pgnum=19&hilite=

Comment: I have also heard about people not wanting to pour the negel vasser down the drain, but out on the ground. I'm pretty sure it's for some kabbalistic reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kaf HaHaim Palagi (8:1)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7882&pgnum=109) writes that if someone doesn't have the cup around his bed, then he should walk four amot and then stop etc. Thus, he holds that one should water around his bed.

Comment: did you ever follow up with Alex link on getting a new print of the Kaf Hachaim I think its marketable Sefer and there should be Many willing to take of monetary responsbility

Comment: @simchashatorah they don't even provide a phone number.

Comment: The Kaf Hachaim says it explicitly, you don't have to infer it (_"Thus, he holds that one should water around his bed"_)

Answer (score 5):

The Mishna Brura (OC 1 sk 2) quotes the Shaarei Teshuva (OC 1 sk 2) who quotes the Birkei Yosef (OC 1 sk 1) who quotes the Bach (OC 4 sk 1) who quotes the Tolaat Yaakov who quotes the Zohar that it is assur to walk 4 cubits before washing upon waking up. It would thus seem prudent to keep a cup of water by one's bed.

Unfortunately, we don't have a Zohar that says that. So I give you: the [Tolaat Yaakov](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43096&st=&pgnum=17&hilite=)!

h/t @simchashatorah for [this bio](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%92%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99) of the Tolaat Yaakov.

Comment: I think this is talking about the idea of not going 4 amot with N"Y (see Reshit Hochma 163b, and Ruah Haim sim. 4).

Comment: http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%92%D7%91%D7%90%D7%99

Comment: @HachamGabriel The only reason to davka wash by your bed is if you can't move to wash elsewhere, no?

Comment: @DoubleAA yes (see my above source).

Comment: @DoubleAA if you can find Ruah Haim 4 of Rav Haim Palagi, I believe it is discussed there.

Comment: http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6445-gabbai#anchor6

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meir_ben_Ezekiel_ibn_Gabbai

Comment: see footnote 84 for some more sources: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=25072&pgnum=34

Comment: Note that in [the footnotes](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh1/1/1/7) brought by Menachem, multiple sources attest to such a version of the Zohar, so the Tolaat Yaakov is not the sole primary source.

Comment: Teshuva MeiAhava 1:14