# Hamapil immediately before sleep, but what about undressing?

Tags: blessing, clothing, tznius-modesty, hefsek-interruption, hamapil

Generally, we are supposed to say hamapil beracha immediately before going to bed, with no interruption. How do we reconcile this with the idea that we should be dressed appropriately to make a beracha, and some people do not sleep in such dress.

Comment: Where is the idea we should be dressed appropriately for making a bracha?

Comment: Well I thought that was just a generally accepted thing. It says so here http://berachot.org/halacha/01_before.html

Comment: That site just says you need to be wearing underwear. Is your question about people who don't even wear that?

Comment: @DoubleAA, sure.

Comment: I think the question would greatly benefit from [editing](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/27851/edit) in (a) what you mean by "dressed appropriately", (b) why you think "we are supposed to say hamapil beracha immediately before going to bed, with no interruption", and (c) why you think "we should be dressed appropriately to make a beracha".

Comment: @msh210 I believe the "without interruption" is a chumra brought by the Mishneh Berurra.  IIRC the Arukh HaShulchan does not rule that way, and neither do the Sephardi poskim.  If I can dig up sources I will actually post an answer.

Comment: I think 'interruption' has a specific definition and means talking. So, for example, between netilat yadayim and ha-motzi, there shouldn't be interruption and that means no talking. It doesn't mean, e.g., no walking from the sink to the table, no sitting down, etc.

Comment: I heard of a yeshiva where the rule was to say HaMapil in the Beis Medresh, in order to prevent socializing in the dorms at bedtime.  Clearly they did not think the interruption was a vital issue

Comment: Do you have the same question about getting dressed in the morning before Hamaavir?

Comment: @RabbiMichaelTzadok I've wondered about the case you bring up for a while but hadn't figured out how to ask it appropriately here.  If you find sources I hope you'll answer this question (which might indirectly answer mine).

Comment: If you want to extrapolate the implication of the order of laws in siman 239, taking off one's garment in order to sleep naked is written after all the laws of krias shema al hamita. The location of the gloss of Ramma where he mentions not to eat drink or talk would also implicate those acts alone are forbidden but the undressing later is not an issue.

Comment: Monica In addition to @user6591's proof which would apply equally to marital relations (whose laws are in Siman 240), the Benei Vinyamin ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=14675&rid=600)) argues that the blessing must be intended to be said beforehand, as afterwards the man ([at least](/q/35064)) would ([have been](/q/38485)) prohibited from reciting blessings. The [Avudarham](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=26840&pgnum=26) proves from the fact that marital relations take place after the blessing (which he takes as obvious) that there is no issue of Hefsek before sleeping

Comment: @Double interesting. But as far as tashmish, aruch hashulchan says to say krias shema afterwards, making sure one is clean and after washing his hands.

Comment: @user6591 That's an acceptable option now that Takkanat Ezra is not binding, but clearly way back when there was only one possible order, so it can't be forbidden to do it that other way.

Comment: @Double True point.

Comment: It was my understanding that the Shema can be said naked as long as one says it while covered with the blanket. It's this allowance that allows people to do the morning berachot while being naked under their covers, and even to say blessed are you lord who clothes the naked while you start covering your nakedness under the covers.

Comment: @Aaron Everyone dressed in clothing is just naked and covered with various pieces of cloth. You haven't​ noted any unique allowance

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://www.yeshiva.co/ask/5891) asks your very question and answers

> There is a dispute among the poskim if Hamapil should be said before
> Shema or just before going to sleep. However, all agree it should be
> as close as possible. The [Mishna Brura (Orach Chaim 239)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.239?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi) says that if
> one is concerned he may fall asleep before saying Hamapil,  it should
> be said before Shema and if one is not concerned it may be said
> afterwards.   Just before sleep most people would be  in their
> pajamas. So as long as your remain modest with your bedclothes you may
> recite Kriyat Shema Al hamita in bedclothes.

Comment: The question was for those who aren't dressed modestly when they sleep

Comment: @robev It seemed he was saying you can say birkas hamapil just before going to bed, which in this case would mean before undressing.