# Consumption of Foods and Liquids Touched By One Who Didn’t Do Morning Netilat Yadayim

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, netilat-yadayim-washing, ruach-rah

My first question is when did the opinion of ruach ra’ah no longer being present today begin? My second question is, are we allowed to consume the foods and drinks touched by one who didn’t do netilat yadayim?

Comment: Q1 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11897/759

Answer (score 1):

In regards to question 2:

[MB 4:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.4.14?lang=bi)

> יד) מפסיד השכר - ואם נגע במאכל קודם שנטל ידיו אין לאסור המאכל עי"ז אבל לכתחילה מאוד יש ליזהר שלא ליגע אז בשום מאכל ואם נגע באוכל ידיחנו ג"פ. וכן אין לשתות עשן טבא"ק קודם נט"י:

> Spoils the beer - If one touched food before washing his hands, the food is not prohibited because of that. But ideally, one should be very careful to not touch any food. And if one did touch food, he should wash it three times. Similarly, one should not (lit. "drink the smoke of tobacco") take a snuff of tobacco?/smoke a cigarette?/smoke a hookah? (not sure exactly what the intended meaning is, but in all three suggestions above, a person touches their hands/fingers to their nose or mouth) before washing their hands.
> (Sefaria)

Comment: I'd translate לשתות עשן טבא"ק as "take a drag of tobacco smoke"